# using global variables inside main() in c

Tags: c, arrays, extern

I'm trying to use global variables, but I'm getting an error when I'm using it inside main function.
Why can't I use "extern" inside main? Codeblocks is showing error in this area only, so I figured out that this is the problem in my code,It is compilation error.
I'm using extern because I don't have to send these arrays to the other function when calling from main()

So what I modify I dorder to make my code work?

I'm trying to print array of integers,intialized with rand().

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check_error(int);
void initialize_array1(int);
void initialize_array2(int);
void print_array1(int);
void print_array2(int);
int find_max(int , int);

void main(void)
{
    int input1,input2;
    printf("Enter the size of the first input: ");
    scanf("%d",&input1);
    while( (check_error(input1)) == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the input again: ");
        scanf("%d",&input1);
    }

    printf("Enter the size of the second input: ");
    scanf("%d",&input2);
    while( (check_error(input2)) == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the input again: ");
        scanf("%d",&input2);
    }
    extern int array1[input1], array2[input2];

    print_array1(input1);
    print_array2(input2);
    find_max(input1,input2);

    printf("\n%d\n",find_max(input1,input2));
}

int check_error(int input)
{
    if(input>0 && input<100)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

void initialize_array1(int input1)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<input1;i++)
    {
        array1[i] = 0;
    }
}


void initialize_array1(int input2)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<input2;i++)
    {
        array2[i] = 0;
    }
}

void print_array1(int input1)
{
    int i;
    printf(" Input array 1");
    for(i=0;i<input1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",array1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_array2(int input2)
{
    int i;
    printf(" Input array 2");
    for(i=0;i<input2;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",array2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int find_max(int input1, int input2)
{
    int max = 0,i;
    for(i=0;i<input1;i++)
    {
        if(array1[i]>max)
        {
            max = array1[i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<input2;i++)
    {
        if(array2[i]>max)
        {
            max = array2[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the error is. Does it compile? Does it link? Also, what are you expecting `extern int array1[input1], array2[input2];` to do?

Answer (score 2):

This code is incorrect for two reasons:

- You declare a variable-length array as external. This is not allowed.
- Even if the arrays were fixed-length, you would need to define these arrays some place else.

To fix this code, define `array1` and `array2` with the `max` size that you expect the users to enter (add validation to make sure that the input size does not exceed `max`).

Here is a link to a answer on a related subject: [What are `extern` variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/335858)

Answer (score 1):

Using `extern` you're **declaring** that this variable is **defined** somewhere else.  BTW, you normally only define (e.g. `int i;`) variables inside a function block.

Something else: Declaring a variable's existence is not enough, it must also be defined somewhere (i.e. space must be set aside for it).

To have a global variable, you at least must define it outside a function.

I think that @dasblinkenlight added a perfect link to his +1 answer!

Comment: You report 'You can only _define_ variables inside a function block." Although unusual, _declaring_ variables inside a function block appears to be valid code. e.g. `int foo(void) { extern int bar; return bar; }
int bar;` Please advise.

Comment: @chux Thanks for the valid remark! Updated my answer.  Thanks for not decrementing immediately.

Comment: Look at my history - no downvotes.  And what you stated certainly would not deserve one.  Further, using extern inside a function opens up an information hiding method of which I was unaware.

Comment: @chux Great! What do you mean with "information hiding method"?

Comment: Information hiding is the control of what one module/class/set of routines sees.   It should see all it needs, no more.  It should make available only what it should and no more.  Well I could go on, but sounds like a good question - maybe its answered all ready.

Comment: @chux I meant, in this context with the `extern` declaration inside a function.  I know what information hiding in general terms is.